# Reducer pattern not updating with new state despite being passed in correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, reduce

My global state isn't updating when I pass an trigger an action:

```
  <TableRow
      hover
      style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
      key={student.authId}
      onClick={() => {
            actions.setSelectedStudent(student);
            setExpanded(!expanded);
       }}
    >
```

Here is the relevant action in my global store file:

```
type State = {
  selectedStudent: StudentNode | null
};

type Action =
  | {
    type: "set_selected_student";
    selectedStudent: StudentNode 
    }
   };


const initialState = {
  selectedStudent: null,
};


const reducer = (state: State, action: Action): State => {
  console.log(action.type)
  switch (action.type) {
      case "set_selected_student":
        return {
          ...state,
          selectedStudent: action.selectedStudent,
        };
    }
    default:
      const unhandledAction: never = action;
      throw new Error(`Unhandled action: ${unhandledAction}`);
  }
};

  const actions = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      setSelectedStudent: (selectedStudent: StudentNode) =>
      dispatch({ type: "set_selected_student", selectedStudent }),
    };
  }, [dispatch]);
```

Here is where dispatch comes from (in the same file)

```
export const useAppState = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

 [...]

  const getActiveStudent = useCallback(
    () => {
      console.log("hello")
      const currentStudent = state.selectedStudent
      return currentStudent
    },
    [state.selectedStudent]
  )
```

It only returns null, which is the initial state, despite the correct argument being passed into the reducer as part of the action.

Comment: Where are you getting dispatch from?

Comment: Same file - I updated OP